# How do I make IIS recognize a directory as a program's folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Because of licensing issues with 3rd party software (It is not necessary for me to go into why) I have to install, what was originally designed to run off the server, onto people's local computers.  The program is an asp.net C# program that uses web.config and IIS.  So I have to go around to everyone's machine that will use this program and set up IIS.  To test how this program will look, I have tried it on my machine.  I get this error:

> This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured
>   as an application in IIS

This means, I guess, that I have to tell the local IIS program that the directory I am using under localhost/wwwroot is a program directory.

How do I do that?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on ServerFault, Stack Overflow is generally more catered to programming specific questions

Answer (score 1):

In IIS expand the site your folder is under (most likely Default Website), right-mouse click on the folder your application is in and select *"Convert to Application"*

[image]

You may also need to configure Application pool used by the application (e.g. make sure that .NET Framework version matches the one used by your application)

Answer (score 1):

Your receiving this issue because *Internet Information System (IIS)* isn't more than likely configured.  In order to correctly configure *Internet Information Systems (IIS)* you'll need to have the following:

- Configure an *Application-Pool*
- Configure your *Application / Site Bindings*

What you should do initially is these steps:

1. Go to **Search**
2. Type **IIS**
3. Select **Internet Information Services Manager**

That should load the application, this is important.  On the left-hand side of the application you should see a *Window* that says **Connections**.  Once you drill your local machine down, you should see *Application Pools* and *Sites*.

This area is where you'll configure the server parameters, so if you go to particular pages in the browser the server will know exactly what to serve to you.

We will configure the *Application-Pool* for your application.

1. Right-Click **Application Pools**
2. Select **Add Application Pool**
3. Put a name, choose your framework, and leave pipeline as **Integrated**.
4. Click **Okay**

Now we will configure our *Site*.

- Right-Click **Sites**
- Select **Add Web-Site**
- Enter the **Site Name**, choose your created **Application Pool**, and point the **Physical Directory** to the location of the application.  Then create a host name, that can be reached (developer.sandbox) for instance.

You've configured your *Internet Information System* to officially serve your pages.  However you'll notice you may not be able to actually reference this URL.  It may demonstrate an error, that is because we need to do two more things.

- Ensure the *IIS-USR / ASP.NET* account that IIS uses is allowed access to your physical directory.
- Force IIS to recognize the URL selected is a `local` through *Host File*.

I'm going to assume you know how to enable access to particular folders, so lets force your page to be looked at as a local site.

1. Open Notepad as **Administrator**.
2. File
3. Open
4. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers`
5. Type `etc`
6. Hit Enter, should of loaded the hidden folder.
7. Type `*.*`
8. Hit Enter
9. Open Host File
10. At the bottom of file put your loopback IP and web-site name: `127.0.0.1 developer.sandbox`

Now when you go to your browser and type `developer.sandbox` it would load your local application you've configured.